# XQE-GEN-0018 QUERY SERVICE INTERNAL ERROR HAS OCCURRED, PLEASE SEE THE LOG FOR DETAILS WHEN QUERYING DMR

Tags: oracle, cognos-bi, cognos-11, report-studio

I am getting error as XQE-GEN-0018 QUERY SERVICE INTERNAL ERROR HAS OCCURRED, PLEASE SEE THE LOG FOR DETAILS.
We have published our CQM package to DQM package . When I point to old package which has type compatible , report run both in Cognos 10 and 11 environment but when I point my report in Cognos 11 environment to Dynamic Type Package , report throws error after I submit prompt values. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you any ad hoc query?
You may have to divide and conquer

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you ought to do is go to the log directory, open the xqe log file, and look for errors at that time stamp.  There will be two entries.  The second one will have the xqe-gen-0018 error in it.  The one before it will have the actual error.

The second thing you ought to do is go into your FM model and look at the things which are going wrong in your query.

Since you say your report has a prompt in it, the third thing you ought to do is look at the data types of the prompt and of the stuff being used in the prompt.